# Protractor "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am doing a test using Protractor. I have the following in my test code:

```
exam.name = element(by.id('name'));
exam.version = element(by.id('version'));

exam.controls = [
    { id: exam.name,      name: 'Name',     control: 'input box' },
    { id: exam.version,   name: 'Version',  control: 'input box' }
];


modal.controlIsPresent = function (data) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            it('Find a\\an ' + data[x].name + ' ' + data[x].control, function () {
                expect(data[x].id.isPresent());
            });
    }
}

modal.controlIsPresent(exam.controls);
```

But when I run my test I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". It is getting the name and control okay. Can someone point out to me what Im doing wrong? Thanks.

What I want to see when I run the test is the following:

```
Find a\an Name input box
Find a\an Version input box
```

Comment: What is the line number of the error? you refer to a couple of properties called `id`.

Comment: Both properties of `id` are giving the same error.

Comment: Is it `by.id` or `data[x].id` ?

Comment: Oh sorry. It's the `data[x].id`. exam.name and exam.version are also used in other part of my test codes and not giving any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.isPresent` is supposed to be used on an element?
Can you use:

```
modal.controlIsPresent = function (data) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            it('Find a\\an ' + data[x].name + ' ' + data[x].control, function () {
                expect(data[x].hasOwnProperty("id"));
            });
    }
}
```